# Run terminal command multiple times for different arguments

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, command-line-interface

I am using the command line for google big query. This is the command im running on the mac terminal:

```
bq load --max_bad_records=100 --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON 
month_of_may.may2016 events-2016-05-09.JSON
```

I want to run this same command for all of the files in the folder.(the file is specified after month_of_may.may2016, i.e "events-2016..." How do i do it?

Comment: Are they all `.JSON` files? or files of any extension

Answer (score 0):

```
  for i in events-2016*
  > do
  > bq load --max_bad_records=100 --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSONmonth_of_may.may2016 $i
  > done
```